# Problemas com array "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined"

Tags: javascript, array

Beleza galera?
Acontece o seguinte, criei uma ferramenta para gerar jogos de azar (quina, mega sena e etc. link da ferramenta: generaterandom.000webhostapp.com)

Na imagem anexada nós vemos a parte onde o algoritmo coloca 60 números aleatórios num array 
Depois é percorrido todo o array para verificar se um número saiu repetido, se ele foi repetido, todos os 60 números são gerados novamente, isso está deixando muito pesado e essa recursão está atrapalhando muito, ocorrendo travamentos e me retorna "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined"

Eu queria saber se é possível otimizar essa parte do código, com apenas um for, gerar 1 número, ver se está no array e adicionar, seria menos linhas, menos for e acredito que não iria travar, porém não consigo fazer essa otimização nas linhas, eu fiz mas não deu certo... alguém pode me orientar? 
link da fuction inteira: generaterandom.000webhostapp.com/gerarJogos.js

```
for (var i = 0; i < comprimento; i++){
    vet[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
}

for (var z = 0; z < comprimento; z++){
   for(var y = 0; y < comprimento; y++){
       if(z !== y){
          if(vet[z] === vet[y]){
             gerarJogos();
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sobre postar código como imagem, por favor leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `while` onde a condição para sair do laço é que o `array` atinja um comprimento de X elementos. Dentro deste `while` você pode usar [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) e testar se o número já existe.

Exemplo:

```js
const comprimento = 5
let numeros = []

while (numeros.length < comprimento) {
  let random = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 60 + 1)
  
  if(!numeros.includes(random)) {
    numeros.push(random)
  } else {
    console.log(`Número repetido, tentando novamente (${random})`)
  }
}

console.log(numeros)
```

Comment: Perfeito cara, perfeito !!

mas não entendi a penultima linha

"numeros = numeros.sort((a, b) => a - b)"

Comment: Eu apenas ordenei os números para ficar mais fácil de ler. Vou atualizar a resposta para explicar como funciona o sort

Comment: mas o que é a ? e o que é b?
e sempre será a, b?

Comment: `a` e `b` são os argumentos recebidos na função de comparação. São nomes que eu escolhi, pode ser o que você achar melhor. Leia a documentação que linkei na resposta que você entenderá melhor

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, nesse primeiro exemplo: [0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
a é 0, b é 3

0 < 3 = então 0 fica em primeiro

depois a é 3, b é 1
3 > 1 = então 1 fica em segundo

depois a é 1, b é 2
1 < 2 = então 2 fica em terceiro

depois a é 2, b é 4
2 < 4 = então 3 fica em quarto

Comment: mas ai nao fez sentido, o 3 ficou de fora da ordenação

Comment: porque esse simbolo de mais igual (=>) e esse menos entre o A e o B? Tem que subtrair os elementos? isso nao ta fazendo sentido

Comment: Eu menciono na resposta: **"Se o resultado da função de comparação for..."**. Quem vai implementar um algoritmo de ordenação é o próprio navegador, você só está dizendo para o navegador como considerar coisas maiores ou menores em relação a elas mesmas.

Comment: E o símbolo `=>` é uma arrow function, que nesse caso seria equivalente a: `[0, 3, 1, 2, 4].sort(function(a, b) { return a - b})`

Comment: Na verdade as edições estão poluindo a resposta e tornando-a confusa. Vou remover a explicação e o código que gerou a confusão, afinal ele não é útil ao objetivo do algoritmo. Qualquer dúvida quando a função sort é só ver na documentação ou abrir um pergunta específica para isso.

Comment: Criei outra pergunta, por favor me ajude

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355661/duvidas-sobre-array-sort

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa para esse problema seria utilizar uma estrutura de dados chamada set, suas duas principais caracteristicas são não permite elementos duplicados e não é uma coleção classificavem.

A lógica fica simplificada dessa forma:

```
let sorteio = new Set();

while(sorteio.size < 6) sorteio.add(Math.trunc(Math.random() * 60 + 1));
```

Comment: Seria interessante usar um `Math.round()` antes de adicionar o número

Comment: Acho mais interessante o `Math.trunc()`, senão pode ocorrer o caso de dar `61` como resultado.

Comment: @fernandosavio, boa, não tinha pensado nisso

Comment: @fernandosavio adicionei o `Math.trunc()` valeu pela correção :)